# check whether a button in another window is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to open a window if a button is clicked, and that button is located in another window. 
So how to check whether a button in another window is clicked or not?

Now I am coding in a class called 'RightButton.cs' 
I want to open a window called 'PopUp' when 'Add' button in 'Reason' window is clicked.

```
PaidOutReason paid = new PaidOutReason(trnprt, apiParameters); 

paid.ShowDialog(); 

if (paid.btnSave.ClickMode == new ClickMode()) 
{ 
    PopUpBanks popu = new PopUpBanks(this); 
    popu.Show(); 
}
```

This one was working perfectly, but I had to remove ShowDialog() and replace it with Show(). Then it was not working.

This is for a POS system. It has a user Control called 'Keyboard'. When the 'Reason' window is opening this Keyboard also want to be opened. Therefore I had to replace ShowDialog() with Show().

Comment: Another window means another window of your application or other running apps ?

Comment: another window in my application

Comment: So why you don't put the window execution code in that window's button ?

Comment: Now I am coding in a class called 'RightButton.cs' I want to open a window called 'PopUp' when 'Add' button in 'Reason' window is clicked.

Comment: Do you use the MVVM pattern and a Dependency Injection container?

Comment: yes MVVM pattern is using

Comment: I am new to this MVVM and now I am using it to my project. Can you help me to solve my problem?

Comment: in the reason window there is the reason, only if the reason is entered and click Add I want to display PopUp window to add the amount. PopUp is a normal window

Comment: It is a window same as the reason window :) with numbers to be clicked and enter button

Comment: Can you please add some sample code to the upper post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the Keyboard Window, I made it a user control and then initialized an event in there. Then I insert that Keyboard User Control to the PaidOutReason Window and then called the event. Then I was able to use ShowDialog() to call the window.

Answer (score 3):

I'd add an event to the window, and bind an event handler to it.

```
class WndWindow{
    BtnPaid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        using(var paid = new PaidOutReason()){
            paid.BtnAddClick += Paid_BtnAddClick;
            paid.ShowDialog();
            paid.BtnAddClick -= Paid_BtnAddClick;
        }
    }

    Paid_BtnAddClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
        var popu = new PopUpBanks();
        popu.Show();
    }
}

class PaidOutReason{
    public event EventHandler BtnAddClick;

    BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        //Do standard event handler code

        BtnAddClick?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

If there's any sort of checks you need to perform you can do that before reading the event, and simply return if checks fail.

Comment: Sorry can you please mention the name of windows and classes as mine. This is somewhat not clear to me.

Comment: I've edited to include your class names and variable names. An event can be used in practically any situation where you need to notify an owning instance of actions you have performed, in this case a when a button is clicked.

Comment: what is this one 'class WndWindow ' and  'Paid_BtnAddClick' ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use static controlls in your app. Start with declaring static window object in App.xaml.cs, for example

```
public static PaidOutReason paidOutWindow;
```

then, in App constructor method, after **InitializingComponent()**, initialize static window class:

```
paidOutWindow = new PaidOutReason();
```

You may wonder what it gives to you. Since it's POS application, you are likely to use the same set of windows quite often and repeatedly, means you can hold window object in memory and refer to it (and change, when needed). Also, after doing such thing, you will have access to all structures inside **PaidOutReason** object, by typing

```
App.paidOutWindow.FunctionName();
```

and finally, you should have access to all window functions such as **ShowDialog()**.

Comment: I will try this one

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVVM pattern, then you can use command binding for showing the PopupBanks window.
For example:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public ICommand AddCommand { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            AddCommand = new RelayCommand(AddCommandHandler);

        }

        private void AddCommandHandler()
        {
            IPopUpBanks popu = new PopUpBanks(this);
            popu.Show();
        }
    }
```

**PaidOutReason** view:
1. `<Button x:Name="Add" Command={Binding AddCommand}/>`
2. Set the above viewmodel as datacontext of PaidOutReason view.

Create a interface IPopUpBanks containing Show() method and implement this interface on **PopUpBanks** view.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `Click` event of `btnSave`:

```
PaidOutReason paid = new PaidOutReason(trnprt, apiParameters);
paid.btnSave.Click += (ss, ee) => 
{
    PopUpBanks popu = new PopUpBanks(this);
    popu.Show();
};
paid.Show();
```